# Split columns based on a specific column

Tags: linux, macos, unix, awk, sed

I have a number of files with 2 or more columns, and I need to split the columns that are not the first based on the first column.
Ex:

```
1 15 90
4 20 89
1 38 129
4 56 150
4 43 171
1 45 210
```

So, I need, in file1:

```
1 15 90
1 38 129
1 45 210
```

And in file 2:

```
4 20 89
4 56 150
4 43 170
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot,
Pedro.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print > ("file" $1)}' file
```